# Django homepage testing error

Tags: python, testing

The below is my python code.

It can pass all except test_home_page_status. I don't know why, and at the bottom is image of error. could you guide me how to fix it?

```
class SimpleTests(SimpleTestCase):
def test_home_page_status(self):
    response = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

def test_info_page_status(self):
    response = self.client.get('/info/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

def test_contact_page_status(self):
    response = self.client.get('/contact/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

def test_admin_login_page_status(self):
    response = self.client.get('/admin/login/?next=/admin/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

[Test Code python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AiaG.png)

Thank you

Comment: You basically have the solution to your error in the error message itself.

Comment: ==> SimpleTests have to inherit from TestCase and not SimpleTestCase